# Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long' al ejecutar controller spring boot desde postman

Tags: java, web, spring, spring-boot, postman

la verdad nunca habia tenido la necesidad de hacer una pregunta, porque siempre
encontraba la solución, esta vez o no la encuentro o no la entiendo.
Estoy ejecutando un endpoint desde Postman, pero me da        error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**EndPoint=**
http://169.60.13.154/psva-api/departments/getModifyMasiveDepAndCentro?
clientId=19&newValue=12&flgChange=G&userId=1&trxWay=4

**Json enviada=**

```
 [
    {"id":44},
    {"id":1245},
    {"id":46},
    {"id":47}
  ]
```

**Error=**
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception
is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "getModifyMasiveDepAndCentro"

Lo extraño que al ejecutarlo desde mi ambiente local funciona de forma correcta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9zYY.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g49dd.png
```

el controller es el siguiente:

```
  @PutMapping("/getModifyMasiveDepAndCentro")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseMessage> getModifyMasiveDepAndCentro(
            @RequestParam(name = "clientId",required = false) Long clientId,
            @RequestParam(name = "newValue",required = false) Long newValue,
            @RequestBody JsonArray listSubscriber,
            @RequestParam(name = "flgChange",required = false) String flgChange,
            @RequestParam(name = "userId",required = false) Long userId,
            @RequestParam(name = "trxWay",required = false) Long trxWay
    )
    {

       return HttpResponseBuilder.buildHttpResponse(departmentService.setModifyDeptCentroCostoMasivetigob(clientId,  newValue,  listSubscriber,  flgChange,  userId,  trxWay));
    }
```

De antemano muchas gracias!!

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para ver las imágenes.  ¿Qué quieres decir con JSON enviada? Ese JSON no corresponde con la URL que muestras ni con la entidad, es solo un array de id. ¿?

Comment: Con lo que muestras vas a tener que compartirnos la traza completa de la excepción para intentar determinar la causa.

Answer (score 0):

Intente cambiando el query param

```
@RequestBody JsonArray listSubscriber,
```

Por este:

```
@RequestBody List<Long> listSubscriber,
```

Haciendo ese cambio, debería cambiar el Json que envía en el cuerpo de la solicitud de esta manera:

```
[
   44,
   1245,
   46,
   47
]
```

Después de recibir el listSubscriber correctamente, ahí sí lo transforma como lo necesite.